# What language is being used in season 2, episode 2 of Evil?

Tags: tv, languages

When David speaks to and/or hallucinates the angel in 'A is for Angel' they both speak in a language other than English. Was this a real (natural) language or a constructed one? It sounded like it could be related to Hebrew, so my money is on Aramaic but I haven't been able to confirm.

Comment: Also asked at https://www.reddit.com/r/EvilTV/comments/wjllna/angel_language_question/ but so far only speculation.